# Mapserver blank image just with "wms_format" "image/png"

Tags: wms, mapserver, png, client

I Have a problem with mapserver 7.0.6 (same with 7.0.4). If I use "wms_format""image/jpeg" everything is fine. But if it's "wms_format" "image/png", there's nothing more than a blank image with QGIS.

The WMS provides both:

```
<GetMap>
<Format>image/jpeg</Format>
<Format>image/png</Format>
```

The layer looks like this:

```
MAP
    NAME "Bodenrichtwerte-Test"
    PROJECTION "init=epsg:25833" END
    IMAGETYPE PNG
    EXTENT 387000 5819000 401000 5838000
    WEB
        METADATA
            "wms_title" "BRW"
            "wms_srs" "EPSG:25833 EPSG:3068"
            "wms_onlineresource" "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/test3.map"
            "ows_enable_request" "*"
            "wms_abstract" "Test"
        END
    END

LAYER
    NAME "BRW_2017"
    TYPE RASTER
    STATUS ON
    CONNECTIONTYPE WMS
    CONNECTION "http://fbintra.senstadt.verwalt-berlin.de/fb/wms/senstadt/brw_2017_amtlich?"
    METADATA
        "wms_srs" "EPSG:25833"
        "wms_title" "Bodenrichtwerte 01.01.2017"
        "wms_name" "2,3"
        "wms_server_version" "1.1.1"
        "wms_format" "image/png"
        "wms_proxy_auth_type" "basic"
        "wms_proxy_host" "*"
        "wms_proxy_port" "*"
        "wms_proxy_type" "*"
        "wms_proxy_username" "*"
        "wms_proxy_password" "*"
    END
END
```

Mapserver:

```
D:\ms4w>mapserv -v
MapServer version 7.0.6 (MS4W 3.2.2) OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS SUPPORTS=SVGCAIRO SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBID
I SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS SUPPORTS=POINT_Z_M INPUT=JPEG
INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE
```

But png's are necessary for the transparancy.

Edit:
It seems to be a problem with png-input in general. I tried it with a testing raster-file. Tif and jpeg is working, png not:

```
LAYER
    NAME "png"
    DATA "D:\raster_test.png"
    TYPE RASTER
    STATUS ON
    PROJECTION "init=epsg:25833" END
    METADATA
        "wms_title" "png-test"
        "wms_srs" "EPSG:25833"
    END
END
```

Any advice?

---

Still I'm a little bit confused, but after updating mapserver to the current version everything works fine.

Comment: I would imagine you need INPUT=PNG in that config list

Comment: And how?
Isn't INPUT=GDAL enough?

Comment: Does the cascaded WMS work OK in QGIS with image/png if you connect it directly?

Comment: Yes, the WMS works directly in QGIS - with both imagetypes.